# unable to view development website when XAMPP is offline

Tags: web, xampp

I have a website under development (stored in my htdocs folder). When disconnected from the internet I am unable to view it in safari even though XAMPP (Apache and mySQL) are running.

How do I change this so that I can develop while offline?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like either that browser tries to be intelligent and react on the disconnection, then maybe you can add an exception? Or you have a routing issue and try to reach your local http server via the remote address? Try connecting manually using telnet as a test: `telnet localhost http` What happens?

Comment: It throws out "localhost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known".

I have XAMPP vhosts set up so that I can access localhost (XAMPP configuration page) at nicolashaigh.dev and then my website at nicolashaigh.dev/nicolashaigh

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that is. It is not an output I would expect from telnet. I can only imagine this: 1. telnet runs into a timeout 2. Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused or 3. the http servers greeting string. I have the impression you did not really make a telnet request but something else. To clearify this: `telnet` is a cli utility. Something like a walkie-talkie. You use it by typing `telnet.....` at a command line prompt, so inside a shell.

Comment: Ah, the second sentence you added to your comment helps: I assumed you tested your setup using the internal 'localhost' host name. This was apparently wrong :-) If you use an internal domain name and that one does not work anymore, then apparently the name resolution stops working the moment you cut the internet connection. How did you achieve the name resolution internally anyway?

Comment: I edited my hosts file:
127.0.0.1 nicolashaigh.dev

Comment: Then apparently that file is not considered during name lookup in your setup. Because neither the browser nor the telnet utility are able to resolve that host. Take a look into the name resolution configuration. That is system dependent. If you use safari then you are using the MacOS system. not familiar with that one, but since apple used BSD as a solid base it should be similar to Linux in that aspect. Is there a resolve.conf file or similar?

Comment: Could it be affected by dnsmasq?

Comment: Okay when I navigate to the resolve.conf file it shows up as an alias (like a shortcut) if you try and open in a text editor it says the original can't be found.

Comment: OK, sorry, as said I have very little idea of the MacOS platform (I prefer Linux). But anyway, this appears to be more a question for the Superadmin sister site, this site here is for programming issues. You can find the link on the bottom of this page. Sorry I cannot be of more help.